# How to deal with overfitting of xgboost classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, xgboost, hyperparameters

I use xgboost to do a multi-class classification of spectrogram images(data link: [automotive target classification](https://de.mathworks.com/help/phased/examples/pedestrian-and-bicyclist-classification-using-deep-learning.html)). The class number is 5, training data includes 20000 samples(each class 5000 samples), test data includes 5000 samples(each class 1000 samples), the original image size is 144*400.  This is my code snippet:

```
train_data, train_label, test_data, test_label = load_data(data_dir, resampleX=4, resampleY=5)
scaler = StandardScaler()
train_data = scaler.fit_transform(train_data)
test_data = scaler.transform(test_data)
cv_params = {'n_estimators': [100,200,300,400,500], 'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.1]}
other_params = {'learning_rate': 0.1,  'n_estimators': 100, 
                'max_depth': 5, 'min_child_weight': 1, 'seed': 27, 'nthread': 6,
                'subsample': 0.8, 'colsample_bytree': 0.8, 'gamma': 0, 
                'reg_alpha': 0, 'reg_lambda': 1,
                'objective': 'multi:softmax', 'num_class': 5}
model = XGBClassifier(**other_params)
classifier = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=cv_params, cv=3, verbose=1, n_jobs=6)
classifier.fit(train_data, train_label)
print("The best parameters are %s with a score of %0.2f" % (classifier.best_params_, classifier.best_score_))
```

During hyperparameter tunning, according to https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/complete-guide-parameter-tuning-xgboost-with-codes-python/, I tuned `n_estimators` at first with `GridSearchCV(n_estimators=[100,200,300,400,500])` using training data, then test with test data. Then I tried GridSearchCV with both 'n_estimators' and 'learning_rate' also.

The best hyperparameter is `n_estimators=500`+ 'learning_rate=0.1' with best_score_=0.83, when I use this best estimator to classify, the training data I get 100% correct result, but the test data only gets precison of `[0.864 0.777 0.895 0.856 0.882]` and recall of `[0.941 0.919 0.764 0.874 0.753]`. I guess with `n_estimators=500` is overfitting, but I don't know how to choose this n_estimator and learning_rate at this step.

For reducing dimensionality, I tried PCA but more than n_components>3500 is needed to achieve 95% variance, so I use downsampling instead as shown in code.

Sorry for the incomplete info, hope this time is clear. Many thanks!

Comment: Please post us all your tuned xgboost's parameters; we need to see them, esp. the important parameters, in particular `max_depth, eta`, etc.  And just because you found the optimal `n_estimators` for GS, that totally doesn't mean your model isn't overfit; those are two different things. All your other parameters might well be leading to overfit.

Comment: Also, you said nothing at all about your data: how many records in training and test, how many classes, what class distribution (imbalanced? what class ratio?) in training, and do you suspect the test set distribution is roughly the same?

Comment: (Please edit all the missing information into the question, not comments here)

Comment: @smci Thanks for your suggestions! I have updated the question description.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try Optuna for XGBoost hyperparameter tuning, with pruning and with early_stopping_rounds parameter of XGBoost ?

Here is a notebook of mine as a guide only.  XGBoost version must be 1.6 though, as early_stopping_rounds is run differently (fit() method) in XGBoost versions below 1.6.

https://www.kaggle.com/code/josephramon/sba-optuna-xgboost